# Share a Wi-Fi connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-shares, ad-hoc-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Share a Wi-Fi connection](https://superuser.com/questions/446186/share-a-wi-fi-connection)

I have a wifi connection [wifi000] and I want to share it. When I use adhoc connection to do this, I have to disconnect from my wifi000. So how can I share my current wifi connection providing another wifi connection or using a cable? I'm using windows7.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the WiFi connection you want to share a connection to? (Is it a client connection?) Why can't other machines just use that same connection? (The solution depends a lot on the problem you're trying to solve.) Also note that you can not bridge to a WiFi client connection.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices

1. You can check this post [VirtualRouter](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/share-internet-connection-wifi-device-virtual-router-windows/), If you have only wifi connection in your laptop(Not connected with Ethernet) then this might prove the best option. It works with Windows 7 and Server 2008. And might need .NET framework(Not to worry Win-7 natively provide it).
2. You may have look at this [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot) post.
    It simply
   says you have to have two NIC:

   1. Ethernet: It connect your computer to internet
   2. Wifi: Now create ad-hoc network that share your internet with other wireless devices.

**Note:**

- Choice 1 Will be good if you have only wifi connectivity at your network.
- If you want to use os features and not to be dependent on 3rd party
  tools then go for Option2.