# Share a Wi-Fi connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a wifi connection `wifi000` and I want to share it. When I use ad hoc connection to do this, I have to disconnect from my `wifi000`. So how can I share my current wifi connection providing another wifi connection or using a cable?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Recommend moving to superuser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share a Wi-Fi connection](http://superuser.com/questions/445990/share-a-wi-fi-connection)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read this article:  http://www.winsupersite.com/article/faqtip/windows-7-tip-of-the-week-use-wireless-hosted-networking-to-share-an-internet-connection-wirelessly

Basically it states that you need to turn on Internet Connection Sharing for the wireless adapter.  On the new adapter that is created, right click to enable.

Open up an administrative command prompt and type this in

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=superuser key=abcd1234`

`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

But as the article states, the best thing to do is to automate it with [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)

Answer (score 0):

Then to share the wifi connection go to

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
```

Right-click the wifi000 adapter, select **Properties**, click the **Sharing** tab, check the box

```
Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection
```

then from the drop-down choose the network adapter through which the others will connect.

Strictly you can only share the wifi000 connection using another network adapter, such as a wired connection. However you can use the Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport adapter to share wifi000 using the same wireless adapter. Select this as the adapter through which to share, and then create an ad-hoc network using it. To do this, go to

```
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center*
```

Then **Manage Wireless Networks**, then **Add**. Select

```
Create an ad-hoc network
```

and follow the prompts to set things up. You should be able to connect other computers to the ad-hoc connection.